# Firebug jumps 'missing ) after element list' when there is ')'

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick

this is my function to update  src value

```
function browse(id,url){
         alert(url);
         document.getElementById("main").value = url ;       
}
```

this is how i call it:

```
<li style="min-width:350px;" title="click to play me"><a href="#"  onclick="browse(68118,http://push2check.com/)" >' . $this->titulo . '</a><li>
```

this is firebug error (of corse the alert is never executed): **missing ) after argument list
[Interrumpir en este error] browse(68118,http://push2check.com/);**

What i dunt understand is the error, is the onclick ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="browse(68118,http://push2check.com/)" >' . $this->titulo . '</a>
```

That URL needs to be quoted:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="browse(68118,'http://push2check.com/')" >' . $this->titulo . '</a>
```

The value you give an "onclick" attribute has to be a valid HTML attribute value that *contains* valid JavaScript. If you wrote:

```
<script>
   var x = http://push2check.com/;
```

you would probably not expect that to work; the URL syntax doesn't mean anything directly to JavaScript, so it would be a syntax error.